# How to create a matrix of polynomials and turn it into systematic form

Tags: matlab

I am currently working on convolutional codes in Matlab. One way to describe such a code is by its parity-check matrix H, which looks e.g. like this for the case of a R = b/c = 2/3 code:

```
[ 1   D   D^3 ]
[ D^3 D^2 1   ]
```

I would like to turn this matrix into systematic form, i.e. the first b x b columns should form an identity matrix. For the above example this would be something like:

```
[ 1   0   ? ]
[ 0   1   ? ]
```

My question is **how can such a matrix, in which each entry is a polynomial, be represented in Matlab** most conveniently? I was thinking of a matrix of coefficient vectors, but this seems kind of unwieldy. At the moment I just can't figure out the best way to approach this problem without creating unnecessary complexity.

Some further remarks:
The coefficients are from GF(2) so all calculations are modulo 2 i.e. 1 + 1 = 0, but this should not be problematic after this question is answered.
General hints and gotchas concerning this topic will be highly appreciated :-)

Question answered by EitanT, with some limitations on the polynomial degree(maximum 64, due to 64 bit precision).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the coefficients belong to GF(2), you can represent each polynomial as a binary number, where each bit represents the corresponding power. For example: D<sup>3</sup>+D<sup>2</sup> = 1100<sub>2</sub> = 12

This allows you to store `H` as a simple matrix and perform rather fast binary operators (such as XOR) when transforming it to reduced row echelon form to obtain the systematic form.

The `H` matrix in your example would look like this:

```
H = [1 2 8;
     8 4 1]
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift answer. I tried it the way you suggest and played around a little, but working with a decimal matrix seems to produce errors due to rounding, e.g. when normalizing an entry of the matrix to 1. If Matlab were to keep fractions as they are, as numerator poly. / denominator poly. , things would be fine. Unfortunately Matlab turns those fractions into type double. For addition(subtraction) and multiplication all operations on the decimal matrix seem to yield the expected results.

Comment: @damage Interesting. What about working with multiples of the denominator (while keeping the factor value in a variable), work with integers and then devide the final result by that factor?

Comment: You are right, this rounding issue can of course be avoided by working with multiples of the denominator and wait with normalization of the diagonal entries until the very end! For my example I get [10 0 17; 0 20 65], with the denominator polynomials on the diagonal of the leading 2 x 2 submatrix. Will confirm your answer after I've written a function for this operation.